# In Flask, whenever i reload the page, last note of list gets added one more time, which I don't want

Tags: python, flask

this is my flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session  
from flask_session import Session


app=Flask(__name__)

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"]=False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"]="filesystem"

Session(app)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])    
def index():
    if session.get("notes") is None:
        session["notes"]=[]
    if request.method=="POST":
        note=request.form.get("note")
        session["notes"].append(note)
    return render_template("index1.html", notes=session["notes"])
```

Problem:

For example, if I write hello and add note, it's get added but when i reload the page, hello is added one more time on its own.

Comment: please add the html code

Comment: `session["notes"].append(note)` would seem to be the culprit here.

Comment: no session["notes"].append(note) that's fine. i think he wants to be added as a list but not when he reload (without submit it) I try his code and same happens to me, it seems this is from the flask_session module. As soon as i add a redirect it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

I think is caused by flask-session module which I personally don't know, however I could fix it by adding url_for with a redirect.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_session import Session


app=Flask(__name__)

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"]=False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"]="filesystem"

Session(app)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])    
def index():
  
    if session.get("notes") is None:
        session["notes"]=[]
    if request.method=="POST":
       
        note=request.form.get("note")
        session["notes"].append(note)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template("index.html", notes=session["notes"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys:
just by adding if else statement:

```
if note in session["notes"]:
                pass
            else:
                session["notes"].append(note)
```